# CodeRay throws error in Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, coderay

I'm running Rails 4 and whenever I try running anything in the rails console, I get the following error:

> ```
> 2.0.0 (main):0 > User.first
> CodeRay::Scanners::Scanner::ScanError:
>
> ***ERROR in scanner.rb:333:in `raise_inspect': no implicit conversion of Array into String (after  tokens)
>
> tokens:
>
>
> current line: 1  column: 5  pos: 4
> matched: nil  state: "Error in CodeRay::Scanners::Ruby#scan_tokens, initial state was: :initial"
> bol?: false,  eos?: false
>
>
> surrounding code:
> ```
>
> nil  ~~  ".first"
>
> ***ERROR***
>
> from /Users/silasjmatson/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/coderay-1.1.0/lib/coderay/encoders/terminal.rb:145:in `text_token'
>
> 2.0.0 (main):0 >

My Gemfile.lock is like so:

```
GIT
  remote: git://github.com/gregbell/active_admin.git
  revision: abb3d454d3a6cb0852be6e7aa4c289ba83e1a966
  branch: master
  specs:
    activeadmin (1.0.0.pre)
      arbre (~> 1.0)
      bourbon
      coffee-rails
      devise (~> 3.0)
      formtastic (~> 2.3.0.rc2)
      inherited_resources (~> 1.3)
      jquery-rails
      jquery-ui-rails
      kaminari (~> 0.13)
      rails (>= 3.2, < 4.1)
      ransack (~> 1.0)
      sass-rails

PATH
  remote: components/api
  specs:
    api (01.0)
      rest-client

PATH
  remote: components/data_models
  specs:
    data_models (0.0.1)
      carrierwave
      fog
      mini_magick
      rails (~> 4.0.0)
      unf

PATH
  remote: components/store
  specs:
    store (0.0.1)
      activemerchant
      coffee-rails (~> 4.0.0)
      compass-blueprint
      compass-rails (~> 2.0.alpha.0)
      country_select
      crummy
      devise (~> 3.1.0)
      devise-async
      geocoder
      heroku-deflater
      jquery-rails
      rails (~> 4.0.1)
      sass-rails (~> 4.0.0)
      sidekiq
      sidekiq-failures
      simple_form
      sinatra
      slim-rails (~> 2.0.1)
      turbolinks
      uglifier (>= 1.3.0)

GEM
  remote: http://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.0.1)
      actionpack (= 4.0.1)
      mail (~> 2.5.4)
    actionpack (4.0.1)
      activesupport (= 4.0.1)
      builder (~> 3.1.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rack (~> 1.5.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
    active_utils (2.0.1)
      activesupport (>= 2.3.11)
      i18n
    activemerchant (1.42.2)
      active_utils (~> 2.0, >= 2.0.1)
      activesupport (>= 2.3.14, < 5.0.0)
      builder (>= 2.1.2, < 4.0.0)
      i18n (~> 0.5)
      json (~> 1.7)
      money (< 7.0.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.4)
    activemodel (4.0.1)
      activesupport (= 4.0.1)
      builder (~> 3.1.0)
    activerecord (4.0.1)
      activemodel (= 4.0.1)
      activerecord-deprecated_finders (~> 1.0.2)
      activesupport (= 4.0.1)
      arel (~> 4.0.0)
    activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
    activesupport (4.0.1)
      i18n (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.4)
      minitest (~> 4.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.3)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.37)
    addressable (2.3.5)
    arbre (1.0.1)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    arel (4.0.1)
    asset_sync (1.0.0)
      activemodel
      fog (>= 1.8.0)
    atomic (1.1.14)
    bcrypt-ruby (3.1.2)
    better_errors (1.0.1)
      coderay (>= 1.0.0)
      erubis (>= 2.6.6)
    binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
      debug_inspector (>= 0.0.1)
    bourbon (3.1.8)
      sass (>= 3.2.0)
      thor
    builder (3.1.4)
    callsite (0.0.11)
    carrierwave (0.9.0)
      activemodel (>= 3.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.2.0)
      json (>= 1.7)
    celluloid (0.15.2)
      timers (~> 1.1.0)
    charlock_holmes (0.6.9.4)
    chunky_png (1.2.9)
    coderay (1.1.0)
    coffee-rails (4.0.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
    compass (0.12.2)
      chunky_png (~> 1.2)
      fssm (>= 0.2.7)
      sass (~> 3.1)
    compass-blueprint (0.0.1)
      compass
    compass-rails (2.0.alpha.0)
      compass (>= 0.12.2, < 0.14)
    connection_pool (1.1.0)
    country_select (1.2.0)
    crack (0.4.1)
      safe_yaml (~> 0.9.0)
    crummy (1.8.0)
    dalli (2.6.4)
    debug_inspector (0.0.2)
    devise (3.1.2)
      bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 3.2.6, < 5)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    devise-async (0.8.0)
      devise (>= 2.2, < 3.2)
    diff-lcs (1.2.5)
    docile (1.1.0)
    dotenv (0.9.0)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    excon (0.28.0)
    execjs (2.0.2)
    factory_girl (4.3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    factory_girl_rails (4.3.0)
      factory_girl (~> 4.3.0)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    ffi (1.9.3)
    figaro (0.7.0)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      rails (>= 3, < 5)
    fog (1.18.0)
      builder
      excon (~> 0.28.0)
      formatador (~> 0.2.0)
      mime-types
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      net-scp (~> 1.1)
      net-ssh (>= 2.1.3)
      nokogiri (~> 1.5)
      ruby-hmac
    foreman (0.63.0)
      dotenv (>= 0.7)
      thor (>= 0.13.6)
    formatador (0.2.4)
    formtastic (2.3.0.rc2)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
    fssm (0.2.10)
    fuubar (1.2.1)
      rspec (~> 2.0)
      rspec-instafail (~> 0.2.0)
      ruby-progressbar (~> 1.0)
    geocoder (1.1.8)
    growl (1.0.3)
    guard (2.2.4)
      formatador (>= 0.2.4)
      listen (~> 2.1)
      lumberjack (~> 1.0)
      pry (>= 0.9.12)
      thor (>= 0.18.1)
    guard-rspec (4.0.4)
      guard (>= 2.1.1)
      rspec (~> 2.14)
    has_scope (0.6.0.rc)
      actionpack (>= 3.2, < 5)
      activesupport (>= 3.2, < 5)
    heroku-deflater (0.5.2)
      rack (>= 1.4.5)
    hike (1.2.3)
    i18n (0.6.5)
    inherited_resources (1.4.1)
      has_scope (~> 0.6.0.rc)
      responders (~> 1.0.0.rc)
    jquery-rails (3.0.4)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    jquery-ui-rails (4.1.0)
      railties (>= 3.1.0)
    json (1.8.1)
    kaminari (0.14.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    listen (2.2.0)
      celluloid (>= 0.15.2)
      rb-fsevent (>= 0.9.3)
      rb-inotify (>= 0.9)
    lockfile (2.1.0)
    lumberjack (1.0.4)
    mail (2.5.4)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    meta_request (0.2.8)
      callsite
      rack-contrib
      railties
    method_source (0.8.2)
    mime-types (1.25)
    mini_magick (3.6.0)
      subexec (~> 0.2.1)
    mini_portile (0.5.2)
    minitest (4.7.5)
    money (6.0.0)
      i18n (~> 0.6.4)
    multi_json (1.8.2)
    net-scp (1.1.2)
      net-ssh (>= 2.6.5)
    net-ssh (2.7.0)
    nokogiri (1.6.0)
      mini_portile (~> 0.5.0)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    pg (0.17.0)
    polyamorous (0.6.4)
      activerecord (>= 3.0)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    pry (0.9.12.3)
      coderay (~> 1.0)
      method_source (~> 0.8)
      slop (~> 3.4)
    pry-rails (0.3.2)
      pry (>= 0.9.10)
    puma (2.6.0)
      rack (>= 1.1, < 2.0)
    rack (1.5.2)
    rack-contrib (1.1.0)
      rack (>= 0.9.1)
    rack-protection (1.5.1)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.2)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.0.1)
      actionmailer (= 4.0.1)
      actionpack (= 4.0.1)
      activerecord (= 4.0.1)
      activesupport (= 4.0.1)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.0.1)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0.0)
    rails_12factor (0.0.2)
      rails_serve_static_assets
      rails_stdout_logging
    rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.1)
    rails_stdout_logging (0.0.3)
    railties (4.0.1)
      actionpack (= 4.0.1)
      activesupport (= 4.0.1)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (10.1.0)
    ransack (1.1.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activerecord (>= 3.0)
      polyamorous (~> 0.6.0)
    rb-fsevent (0.9.3)
    rb-inotify (0.9.2)
      ffi (>= 0.5.0)
    rb-readline (0.5.0)
    rdoc (3.12.2)
      json (~> 1.4)
    redis (3.0.6)
    redis-namespace (1.3.2)
      redis (~> 3.0.4)
    responders (1.0.0)
      railties (>= 3.2, < 5)
    rest-client (1.6.7)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
    rspec (2.14.1)
      rspec-core (~> 2.14.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.14.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.14.0)
    rspec-core (2.14.7)
    rspec-expectations (2.14.4)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.1.3, < 2.0)
    rspec-instafail (0.2.4)
    rspec-mocks (2.14.4)
    rspec-rails (2.14.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      railties (>= 3.0)
      rspec-core (~> 2.14.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.14.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.14.0)
    ruby-hmac (0.4.0)
    ruby-progressbar (1.2.0)
    safe_yaml (0.9.7)
    sass (3.2.12)
    sass-rails (4.0.1)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.10)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0.0)
    sdoc (0.3.20)
      json (>= 1.1.3)
      rdoc (~> 3.10)
    sidekiq (2.16.1)
      celluloid (>= 0.15.2)
      connection_pool (>= 1.0.0)
      json
      redis (>= 3.0.4)
      redis-namespace (>= 1.3.1)
    sidekiq-failures (0.2.2)
      sidekiq (>= 2.9.0)
    simple_form (3.0.0)
      actionpack (>= 4.0.0, < 4.1)
      activemodel (>= 4.0.0, < 4.1)
    simplecov (0.8.1)
      docile (~> 1.1.0)
      lockfile (>= 2.1.0)
      multi_json
      simplecov-html (~> 0.8.0)
    simplecov-html (0.8.0)
    sinatra (1.4.4)
      rack (~> 1.4)
      rack-protection (~> 1.4)
      tilt (~> 1.3, >= 1.3.4)
    slim (2.0.2)
      temple (~> 0.6.6)
      tilt (>= 1.3.3, < 2.1)
    slim-rails (2.0.3)
      actionpack (>= 3.0, < 4.1)
      activesupport (>= 3.0, < 4.1)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 4.1)
      slim (~> 2.0)
    slop (3.4.7)
    sprockets (2.10.0)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sprockets-rails (2.0.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      sprockets (~> 2.8)
    sqlite3 (1.3.8)
    subexec (0.2.3)
    temple (0.6.7)
    thor (0.18.1)
    thread_safe (0.1.3)
      atomic
    tilt (1.4.1)
    timers (1.1.0)
    treetop (1.4.15)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    turbolinks (1.3.1)
      coffee-rails
    tzinfo (0.3.38)
    uglifier (2.3.1)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      json (>= 1.8.0)
    unf (0.1.3)
      unf_ext
    unf_ext (0.0.6)
    vcr (2.7.0)
    warden (1.2.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    webmock (1.16.0)
      addressable (>= 2.2.7)
      crack (>= 0.3.2)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  activeadmin!
  api!
  asset_sync
  better_errors
  binding_of_caller
  charlock_holmes
  coderay (~> 1.1.0)
  dalli
  data_models!
  factory_girl_rails
  figaro
  foreman
  fuubar
  growl
  guard
  guard-rspec
  jquery-rails
  meta_request
  pg
  pry-rails
  puma
  rails (= 4.0.1)
  rails_12factor
  rb-readline (~> 0.5.0)
  redis
  rspec-rails
  sdoc
  sidekiq
  simplecov
  sqlite3
  store!
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  vcr
  webmock
```

**Any Help?**

Comment: Here's the relevant line of code in Coderay: https://github.com/rubychan/coderay/blob/master/lib/coderay/scanner.rb?source=c#L333

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try removing `pry` from your Gemfile.

Comment: I would [open an issue](https://github.com/pry/pry/issues) on Github. They would know better what's going on here.

Comment: @Silasj: I ran into a similar issue today and found it was a problem in my `~/.pryrc`.  Some old hack there was outdated and causing the issue.  See [here](https://github.com/pry/pry/issues/1012) for details.

Answer (score 6):

If you're like me and want to keep using pry, changing your Gemfile to have the following fixes this issue.

```
gem "pry", "0.9.12.2"
```

Answer (score 1):

I removed any CodeRay related code from my .pryrc and it works again.